# How to display json formatted string NSTextview

Tags: json, cocoa, nstextview

I want to display a formatted `JSON` string in an `NSTextView`.
If I set it directly it will display as continues string, but I need it as formatted like

```
{    
    "0":"N",
    "J":5    
}
```

Is there any inbuilt method or 3rd party opensource library to format json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of JSON parsing frameworks have the option of pretty printing.

For instance `SBJsonWriter`. It has a  `humanReadable` property.

> If set to YES, generates human-readable JSON with linebreaks after
>   each array value and dictionary key/value pair, indented two spaces
>   per nesting level.

If you just want the indentation logic you can dig in and just use that part and strip your project of unnecessary SBJson files.

**EDIT:**

From OS X 10.7, `NSJSONSerialization` is available natively in Cocoa.

You can pass the `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted` as an option to 
`+dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` class method of `NSJSONSerialization` to achieve what you want.